# MySQL insert issue

Tags: mysql, insert, replace, double-quotes

I am attempting to insert data into a table that contains a lot of single and double quotes.

```
INSERT INTO vulnerabilities_internal_test (device_type, ip_address, user_tag, 
repositoryID, severity, pluginID, pluginName, pluginText)

VALUES ("@Data.device_type~", "@Data.ip_address~", "@Data.user_tag~", 
"@Data.repositoryID~", "@Data.severity~", "@Data.pluginID~", "@Data.pluginName~", 
replace(replace("@Data.pluginText~", ',', ''), '"', '' ))
```

I am receiving the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Thorough tests" was not enabled\nwhen this scan was run.\n\nCVE : CVE-2011-1000,' at line 3

However the data looks like this:

Thorough tests" was not enabled\nwhen this scan was run.\n\nCVE : CVE-2011-1000

Does anyone have an idea why one of the double quotes being replaced with a single quote and throwing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter. The problem is that your data should have all quotation marks escaped with a slash ('\'). That way, you just need to unescape the data when returning results to your code.

Comment: I have no control over the data, it is coming in from an external tool. I am just trying to insert it into a new database

Comment: What do you mean by no control, can't you clean the data before inserting?

Comment: I am not sure how to, I am connected the backend database of a network scanning tool and trying to insert scan results from  into a MySQL database that I set up to work with the data.

Comment: There would be no need to unescape the data when returning results from the db.